# Fast C++ I/O to read a string (char array) into a vector, plus resolving error

Tags: c++, string

Right now I am trying to use a vector of charpointers to hold a bunch of individual strings

```
vector<char*> strings(10);
```

The individual string is of form `char indString[100]`

And I am doing this to assign each one

```
for (int i=0; i < iLimit; ++i){
    gets(indString);
    strings[i] = indString;
}
```

But when I output everything

```
for (auto & stri: strings) cout << stri << endl;
```

I just get a bunch of repeats of the last string read.

Comment: Silly question - but are you incrementing `i` in between read operations? Need to show a bit more code...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-is-dangerous-why-should-not-be-used

Comment: @Mat I know the max size of the inputs

Comment: Show enough code that we can reproduce your problem. Right now this doesn't run.

Comment: @Floris I added the iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pointing all your `strings[i]` to the same location... you need to allocate different memory locations for each string, and read them into that location. With char arrays, it would look like this:

```
char* strings[10];

for (int i=0; i < iLimit; ++i){
    strings[i] = malloc(sizeOfLargestString + 1);
    gets(strings[i]);
}
```

Or full code (tested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define sizeOfLargestString 100
#define N 3

int main(void) {
  int ii;
  char* strings[N];
  for (ii=0; ii < N; ii++) {
    strings[ii] = (char*)malloc(sizeOfLargestString + 1);
    gets(strings[ii]);
  }
  for(ii=0 ;ii< N; ii++) {
    printf("%s\n", strings[ii]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't technically work. I am trying to hold an array of strings basically

Comment: "error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]" on the strings[i] = malloc line

Comment: I have edited so your compiler ought not to complain (tested with `gcc - Wall`)

Comment: outputs a blank line at the front, then outputs the rest fine, ignores the last line of input

Comment: just used a workaround (read string once arbitrarily before the loop) and I think it works now... thanks!

Comment: I did strings[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeOfLargestString+ 1); gets(strings[0]); before the input loop

Answer (score 1):

You are just storing the pointer to the buffer used to read... all the pointers will point to the same buffer and this is why you see the last string repeated.

Just use an `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: I'd like to do this without strings if possible, I get a speed advantage using char arrays

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same pointer to the `vector` at every iteration which is causing you to see duplicates in the output. You can do this *efficiently* and *cleanly* using `std::getline`, `std::string` and `std::move`.

Below is a working example that reads strings from `cin` and outputs the contents of the vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void readtext(
    std::istream& input,
    std::vector<std::string>& text,
    const size_t limit)
{
    std::string line;
    for (size_t count = 0; count < limit && std::getline(input, line); ++count)
        text.push_back(std::move(line));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> text;
    readtext(std::cin, text, 3);
    for (auto& line : text)
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They all are pointing to the same pointer. I'd suggest doing this:

```
char** PointerArray = new char*[NumOfStrings];

//input strings

for( int i = 0; i < NumOfStrings; i++ )
     cout << PointerArray[i];

for( int i = 0; i < NumOfStrings; i++ )
     delete[] PointerArray[i];
```

EDIT: If you require vectors, make an array of character arrays, then pass each character into it.

OR you could try this:

```
char** PointerArray = new char*[NumOfStrings];

vector<char*> pointerArray(NumOfStrings);
for( int i = 0; i < NumOfStrings; i++ )
     pointerArray[i] = PointerArray[i];
//stuff
for( int i = 0; i < NumOfStrings; i++ )
     delete[] pointerArray[i];
```